# Post in multiple categories

Tags: categories

I try to list posts in multiple categories. Everything goes fine in the admin panel. I go into all posts, i select desired posts, after that i go into edit and select one category. After i save the changes, under categories tab is written the old category and the new one.
Now when i visit website and i select updated category there is only the old posts and not new ones .

For example:
I have categories:
movies , games , best
and posts:
best movie , best games , best
And i need like that:
best movies goes in movie category
best games goes in games category
and both goes in best category

I use date and post name  as permalinks.

Comment: It could be a case of caching. Are you running any caching plugins, or does your host enforce aggressive caching?

Answer (score 0):

As long as there isn't any technical issue on your site, such as plugin incompatibility or another glitch, the most common reason for your changes not appearing on the site is cache.

You may have cache on the site, the server, a CDN or intermediate cache.
Try to hard-refresh or disable cache plugins temporarily.

If that doesn't seem to be the issue, more information is needed to troubleshoot or a link to the site to take a look, together with an example of a post that behaves as you say.

Do your new posts get published at all? If not, it might be php limitations that give you problems.

Comment: All my new posts get published.                                                                                As cache plugin i got W3 Total Cache but is not activated.                                          Now i have to go to work, but i will try to delete all plugins i do not use, i will come back with feedback.

Comment: I did everything you said and nothing works. After that i did a small test. I installed xampp in my computer, after that wordpress. I made 3 categories and i wrote 4 posts in first two , after i updated all posts to be seen in thirst category. Everything works fine. I installed theme i use on my website and surprise ... is not working anymore. Anyone know what files i have to look into and what code i have to change?